# Regex for more results locator on google scholar

Tags: python, web-scraping

I would like to click on more results on google scholar from Python software. But I cannot find the correct XPATH. I have located the results button but not the link to the next site which seems to be in the span one level below as can be seen from the picture. I have tried `"//button[@aria-label='Next']"` and `"//button[@aria-label='Next']\span"` and `"//button[@aria-label='Next']\span\span[1]"`. why does this not work?

```
url = "https://scholar.google.ch/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=bla&btnG="
driver = webdriver.Chrome("~/chromedriver")

driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Next']").click()
```

I get the error, `element not clickable` because I cannot access the position of the real button.

Below a screenshot of the node structure in the html.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using chrome Dev-Tools, you can select the element and click on `Copy XPath`. This will give you a selector that is guaranteed to work with that element. I've attached an image that displays this:

[image: How to copy XPath of element]

This is what it returned: `//*[@id="gs_n"]/center/table/tbody/tr/td[12]/a/b`

However, this can be further tuned. After some analysis, I found that `//*[(@id = "gs_n")]//a//b` works just as well.

Since you are using the chrome driver, these values should work fine since the DevTools is the one that generated it.

#### Edit

I think that we were referring to different selectors, thus creating a problem for you. Consider the screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of DevTools that shows why OP couldn't find proper XPath]

The blue highlight represents the element that I used while the green highlight represents what I think you focused on. As a general note, try to right click on the specific element you want when using `Inspect Element`.

Comment: wow that's great thank you and it works with the xpath you indicate but I can for some reason not see the part that you show in your picture. And using that very same way of obtaining my xpath for the element that appears when clicking 'inspect', and then copy the xpath from the element selected, I get a different xpath. Also when searching for the element you indicated, I don't see a reaction on screen that it is the more results button even though it works Do you know why this could be?

Comment: why do you get such a different excerpt of the html than in my screenshot?

Comment: I can't say for sure why our excerpts are different. After all I did use the exact same URL that you provided. I suspect that we are both referring to different elements. I added a different screenshot to my answer to show what I think we both were referring to

Comment: Also, I'd appreciate it if you could mark the answer as correct since it ended up solving your problem.